# android which values folders i have created for support all resolutions include 7' and 10' tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created values folder like
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
values-xhdpi
values-xxhdpi
values-sw600dp for 7' tablet
values-sw720dp for 10' tablet
But it not works perfectly , please suggest better option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Create your folder according to screen size:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp (**values-xlarge**)
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp(**values-large**)
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp(**values-normal**)
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp(**values-small**)

[image]

you should use the **values-large** to support 7 inch screen regardless of the density.

you should use the **values-xlarge** to support 10 inch screen regardless of the density.

for more details : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: did i manage all resolutions for using this 4 folders ? and also 1 question in this folders put dimens files for margin, height etc , so how define all sizes for different values folder

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Use
**values-sw600dp** for tab 7 inch
**values-sw1280dp** xxhdpi
**values-sw480dp** mdpi
**values-sw720dp** xhdpi
**values-sw800dp** tab 10 inch
these values folder will support most of devices.

Comment: values-sw600dp for both size tablet 7 inch & 10 inch?

Comment: values-sw800dp for 10 inch

Comment: and for other phone resolutions like hdpi, mdpi?

Comment: values-sw1280dp, values-sw480dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp, values-sw800dp will support almost all devices.

Comment: thanks buddy & also 1 question in this folders put dimens files for margin, height etc , so how i can define all sizes for different values folder

Comment: means which best site for px to dp convertor?

Comment: ok, for conversion you can use this site: http://androidpixels.net/  please accept(like) my answer. Most android designers use this site

Comment: sorry but i dont like ur comment now , because my reputation is 1